# Getting no result rows/fields from php/mysqli query while there is data

Tags: php, mysql

Explanation of the issue is:

- Query sql returns 6 rows of data (of 14 fields each) when run in
  phpMyAdmin
- On the php page mysqli_num_rows returns: 6
- `print_r($sql_res)` returns:  `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 14 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 6 [type] => 0 )`
- `var_dump($sql_res)` returns:  `object(mysqli_result)#1 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(14) ["lengths"]=>
  NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(6) ["type"]=> int(0)`

There is data in the db, but is not being parsed into the table structure since no data containing field values are returned. Any help or pointers would highly be appreciated.
DB connection is OK, my other pages are working, I'm using session variables in query ($selected and $selfair), my php code that gives the headache is:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT har_id, har_fair_id, har_kat_id, har_tarih, har_co_id, har_desc, har_docno, har_kur, har_debit, har_credit, har_used, har_invoiced, har_cancelled, har_schid FROM hareketler WHERE har_co_id =". $selected." AND har_fair_id =". $selfair;
echo $sql."<br><br>";
//sql returns correct statement
$sql_res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
print_r($sql_res)."<br><br>";
echo "<br><br>".mysqli_num_rows($sql_res);
// row count is 6 but no other data is fetched from db!
echo "<br><br>".var_dump($sql_res);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res,MYSQLI_ASSOC));{
// detail rows are NOT fetched!
    if($row<>''){
    echo '<tbody>';
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_fair_id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_kat_id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_tarih'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_co_id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_desc'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_docno'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_kur'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_debit'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_credit'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_used'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_invoiced'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_cancelled'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="katdata">'.$row['har_schid'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    echo '</tbody>';
    }
    else {
        echo "<br><br>No data returned!";
        // sql is correct but no detail data is fetched!
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome. That `;` in your `while` statement does work?

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL injections..(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) you should prevent them ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php )

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks a million! I guess I really need better glasses!
I'm also sorry for occupying time here for a stupid typo... Thanks again.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  Thanks Raymond, I will read those articles.

Comment: "_I guess I really need better glasses!_" Or a decent IDE! Or error_reporting! ;) Glad it works.

Comment: I use Sublime Text, not any IDE's maybe I should turn to one... Well at 64, that's what you get. :-D

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res,MYSQLI_ASSOC));{
```

should be

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that there is a single quote(') around the values you are comparing.
For instance

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name = 'value';
```

will work, but

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name = value;
```

will not work.

So make sure your output is:

```
SELECT har_id, har_fair_id, har_kat_id, har_tarih, har_co_id, har_desc, har_docno, 
har_kur, har_debit, har_credit, har_used, har_invoiced, har_cancelled, har_schid 
FROM hareketler WHERE har_co_id ='selected' AND har_fair_id ='selfair';
```

To achieve this, change your sql to

```
$sql = "SELECT har_id, har_fair_id, har_kat_id, har_tarih, har_co_id, har_desc, 
har_docno, har_kur, har_debit, har_credit, har_used, har_invoiced, har_cancelled, 
har_schid FROM hareketler WHERE har_co_id ='". $selected."' AND har_fair_id ='". 
$selfair."';";
```

This Should Solve your problem, that, and there is a misplaced semicolon in your while loop. `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res,MYSQLI_ASSOC));{`. You need to fix that
Thank You, hope this was helpful.

Comment: Whilst that's all true, concatenating a value into a SQL string is not a good idea as it opens you up to SQL injection attacks. Better approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I use PDO objects, its much safer